# How to change the default color on a MTL file?

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

```
Here is the Code Pen Link, using THREE JS:
```

https://codepen.io/FarhaNaseem/pen/NWdgYQJ

What I basically have is a 3d Model with a basic color setup on the MTL file. Is there is a way to add a color scheme and change the colors on clicking ? Please note that this has to be done separately for the bottle as well as the cap.

For example, the cap can have color options such as Gold, Green, Blue.
And the bottle can have color options such as Yellow, Orange , Pink.

Also what are the possibilities of doing this with out the GUI.dat library?

Comment: Please include the code from your codepen, so that the question retains its context, even when (not if) the codepen link changes or disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback for [`MTLLoader.load`](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=mtll#examples/en/loaders/MTLLoader.load) receives a `MTLLoader.MaterialCreator` (which is not documented). In your code, that is the `material` parameter here:

```js
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
mtlLoader.load( mtlURL, function( material ){ // <-- the MaterialCreator
  // ...
});
```

After calling `preload`, the `material` object will populate its `materials` property with the material names as defined in the MTL. If you debug your code, you will see that you have two `MeshPhongMaterial`s named `blinn5SG` and `blinn8SG`.

#### Changing the color at load time

At this point (before you load your object), you can manipulate the color.

```js
material.materials.blinn5SG.color.setHex( bottleColorHex );
material.materials.blinn8SG.color.setHex( capColorHex  );
```

#### Changing the color at runtime

You could also save off the materials into globally-accessible variables to access at runtime:

```js
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
var bottleMaterial = null;
var capMaterial = null;
mtlLoader.load( mtlURL, function( material ){ // <-- the MaterialCreator
  material.preload();
  bottleMaterial = material.materials.blinn5SG;
  capMaterial = material.materials.blinn8SG;
  //...
});

// later...

function changeColor( material, newHexColor ){
  material.color.setHex( newHexColor );
  material.needsUpdate = true;
}
// examples:
changeColor( bottleMaterial, newBottleHexColor );
changeColor( capMaterial, newCapHexColor );
```

Note that at runtime you need to set [`material.needsUpdate`](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=Material#api/en/materials/Material.needsUpdate) to `true` to tell the renderer that the material has changed.